# polymer bind data to div id

Tags: javascript, arrays, data-binding, polymer

I have a polymer element in which I can declare an array and use it as below.

```
  ...
  <template repeat="{{chapters as chapter}}">
    <core-submenu id='{{chapter.id}}-core-submenu' label="{{chapter.label}}">
    </core-submenu>
  </template>
  ...
  Polymer('app-element', {
    chapters: [{id: one, label: one}, {id: two, label: two}],
    ...
    somethingChanged : function(){
      this.$[this.chapter.id + '-core-submenu']
    }
    ...
}
```

It works as expected if I fill the chapters object as above.

I want to will this chapters from outside. I then do the following:

```
  var app = document.querySelector('#app');
  window.addEventListener('polymer-ready', function() {
    app.chapters = [{id: one, label: one}, {id: two, label: two}];
  });
```

If I do that, this.$[this.chapter.id + '-core-submenu'] is now null. I guess it happens because the this.$ is filled before the polymer-ready event is fired.

Does it make sense? Which would be the best practice to now access this element? I was hoping to still be able to access it through this.$.

Best
Nicolas

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to expose this property as polymer attribute and then access that from outside using setAttribute

```
window.addEventListener('polymer-ready', function() {
    var app = document.querySelector('#app');
    app.setAttribute('chapters',[{id: one, label: one}, {id: two, label: two}]);
});
```